# L1 Norm Optimization Solution

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, normed-spaces, absolute-value, subgradient

I am trying to find the solution for the following optimization problem:

$\max_{w} {z^Tw - \lambda ||w - w_0||_1}$ 
where $z, w, w_0 \in R^{Nx1}$ and $z, w_0$ are known.

We let $s$ be the subgradient of $\lambda ||w - w_0||_1, \hspace{2mm} s \in \{ {u | u^T(w - w_0) = \lambda ||w - w_0||_1, ||u||_{\infty} \leq \lambda \}  }$.

If we write $\lambda ||w - w_0||_1 = \max_{||s||_{\infty} \leq \lambda} s^T(w - w_0)$, the objective function can now be written as: 
$\max_{w} \min_{||s||_{\infty} \leq \lambda} {z^Tw - s^T(w - w_0)}$ 
$\min_{||s||_{\infty} \leq \lambda} \max_{w} {z^Tw - s^T(w - w_0)}$.

The first order condition for the inner objective function is: 
$0 = z - s \hspace{1cm}   [1]$ 
Substituting [1] into the objective function, 
$\min_{||s||_{\infty} \leq \lambda} s^Tw_0$.

Hence, this objective function can be simplified as, 
$\min_s s^Tw_0 \text{ s.t } -\lambda \leq s \leq \lambda$.

However, if all the steps above are correct (which I am not very certain about), I am not sure how the solution of *s* from the "simplified" optimization above will help me solve for *w*. 
The sequence of steps taken to solve the initial optimization problem was inspired by the [following paper](http://faculty.london.edu/avmiguel/MDN-JBF.pdf).

Any help on this is very much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a slight error in your derivation: you cannot set $s=z$ if $||z||_\infty > \infty$. Otherwise, the solution to
$$\min_s \left\{ s^Tw_0 : -\lambda \leq s \leq \lambda \right\}$$
is trivial: you set $s_i = \lambda$ if $w_0\leq 0$, and $s_i = -\lambda$ otherwise, resulting in the objective value $-\lambda||w_0||_\infty$ (but again, this is wrong because you cannot always have $s=z$).

I would solve the optimization problem like this:
\begin{align}
\max_{w} {z^Tw - \lambda ||w - w_0||_1} &= \max_{w} {z^T(w+w_0) - \lambda ||w||_1} \\
&= z^T w_0 + \max_{w} {z^Tw - \lambda ||w||_1} \\
&= \begin{cases} z^T w_0 & \text{if } ||z||_\infty \leq \lambda \\ \infty & \text{otherwise.}\end{cases}
\end{align}
The last step is like [computing the dual of the 1-norm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3021119/dual-norm-of-l-1-of-is-l-infty).

Comment: this is very helpful. The solution implies that the problem is unbounded above if $||z||_{\infty} > \lambda$. I was wondering if you have an intuitive reasoning as why this might be true. We can achieve a very large objective value by setting the appropriate $w_i$, where _i_ is $max_i |z_i| $, to be very large. However, there is a penalty for $||w-w_0||_1$. Is the condition, $||z||_{\infty} > \lambda$ sufficient to indicate that the increase from $z^Tw$ will dominate that of $\lambda ||w-w_0||_1$?

Comment: @vpy your comment is answered in the linked question. If $z_i > \lambda$ for some $i$, letting $w_i \to \infty$ makes the expression go to $\infty$ (if $z_i < -\lambda$, let $w_i \to -\infty$).

Comment: thanks. I see it now. If it is not too much to ask, I have a quick follow-up question. Do you know if it is possible to analytically derive the value of $w^*$ that optimizes a norm-based objective function. In the example above, $w^*$ is obvious. However, consider an alternative optimization like, $\max_{x} \mu^Tx - \gamma ||x-x_0||_1$ 
s.t. $\phi^Tx = 0.15$. In this case, in attempt to find $w^*$ I tried to write the Lagrangian, $L(x, \lambda) = \mu^Tx - \gamma ||x-x_0||_1 - \lambda (0.15 - \phi^Tx)$. However, before I can evaluate the F.O.C, I need to find an alternative expression for abs.

Comment: @vpy the solution does not immediately come to mind, but try deriving the dual using my answer and see if you can solve it analytically. If not, please ask in a new question.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried fiddling with this problem for a while. I am not able to see how I could use the complementary slackness relationship between the dual and primal to solve for $w^*$ analytically. Posted a follow up question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4131509/inequality-constrained-norm-minimization.