# prove about $\|\boldsymbol{v}\|_{\infty}$

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

I have to prove $$\|\boldsymbol{v}\|_{\infty}=\sup _{\|\boldsymbol{u}\|_1=1}\left|\boldsymbol{v}^* \boldsymbol{u}\right|=\max _{\|\boldsymbol{u}\|_1=1}\left|\boldsymbol{v}^* \boldsymbol{u}\right|$$

taking into account vectorial norm properties

a) $$\frac{1}{n}\|\boldsymbol{v}\|_1 \leq\|\boldsymbol{v}\|_{\infty}
\leq\|\boldsymbol{v}\|_1$$
b) $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\|\boldsymbol{v}\|_1 \leq\|\boldsymbol{v}\|_2 \leq\|\boldsymbol{v}\|_1$$
c) $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\|\boldsymbol{v}\|_2 \leq\|\boldsymbol{v}\|_{\infty} \leq\|\boldsymbol{v}\|_2$$
d) $$\lim _{p \rightarrow+\infty}\|\boldsymbol{v}\|_p=\|\boldsymbol{v}\|_{\infty}$$

I don't see a path to continue the proof. Is there any other way to do this. Any idea? thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dual norm of $l_1$ of is $l_\infty$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3021119/dual-norm-of-l-1-of-is-l-infty)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i can do this proof, for all $\boldsymbol{v}\in\mathbb{K}^n$ y $\boldsymbol{u}\in\mathbb{K}^n$ with $\|\boldsymbol{u}\|=1$, then by triangular inequality
$$
    |\boldsymbol{v}^*\boldsymbol{u}|  =  |\bar{\boldsymbol{v}}_1\boldsymbol{u}_1+\bar{\boldsymbol{v}}_2\boldsymbol{u}_2+\cdots+\bar{\boldsymbol{v}}_n\boldsymbol{u}_n| \leq  |\bar{\boldsymbol{v}}_1||\boldsymbol{u}_1|+|\bar{\boldsymbol{v}}_2||\boldsymbol{u}_2|+\cdots+|\bar{\boldsymbol{v}}_n||\boldsymbol{u}_n|\\
         \leq  \sum_{i=1}^n |\bar{\boldsymbol{v}}_i||\boldsymbol{u}_i|
$$
Now as $|\bar{\boldsymbol{v}}|=|\boldsymbol{v}|$ and consider the maximum over the $i\in \{1, \ldots, n\}$ of the $|\boldsymbol{v}_i|$ then
\begin{equation*}
        \begin{split}
            |\boldsymbol{v}^*\boldsymbol{u}| \leq & \sum_{i=1}^n |\bar{\boldsymbol{v}}_i||\boldsymbol{u}_i|\\
            \leq & \max_{j\in \{1, \ldots, n\}} |\boldsymbol{v}_j| \sum_{i=1}^n |\boldsymbol{u}_i|\\
             = & \max_{j\in \{1, \ldots, n\}} |\boldsymbol{v}_j| = \|\boldsymbol{v}\|_\infty
        \end{split}
    \end{equation*}
How $\|\cdot\|$ is a continuous function on a compact, this guarantees us the existence of the supremum there and so
$$\sup_{\|\boldsymbol{u}\|=1}|\boldsymbol{v}^*\boldsymbol{u}|  \leq \|\boldsymbol{v}\|_\infty$$
Finally, let's look at the other inequality
\begin{equation*}
        \begin{split}
            \|\boldsymbol{v}\|_\infty &= \max_{i\in \{1, \ldots, n\}} |\boldsymbol{v}_i| \|\boldsymbol{u}\|_1\\
            & = \sum_{j=1}^n \max_{i\in \{1, \ldots, n\}} |\boldsymbol{v}_i||\boldsymbol{u}_j|\\
            & \geq \sum_{j=1}^n |\boldsymbol{v}_i||\boldsymbol{u}_j|\\
            & = \sum_{j=1}^n |\bar{\boldsymbol{v}}_j\boldsymbol{u}_j|\geq |\boldsymbol{v}^*\boldsymbol{u}|
        \end{split}
    \end{equation*}
Again, we are in a compact and the function is continuous, then
$$ \|\boldsymbol{v}\|_\infty\geq\sup_{\|\boldsymbol{u}\|=1}|\boldsymbol{v}^*\boldsymbol{u}|$$
On the other hand we have that the supremum is bounded by the maximum, then
$$\|\boldsymbol{v}\|_\infty \leq \sup_{\|\boldsymbol{u}\|=1} |\boldsymbol{v}^*\boldsymbol{u}|\leq \max_{\|\boldsymbol{u}\|=1} |\boldsymbol{v}^*\boldsymbol{u}|$$
from which it follows that
\begin{equation*}
        |\boldsymbol{v}^*\boldsymbol{u}|  \leq  \sum_{i=1}^n |\bar{\boldsymbol{v}}_i||\boldsymbol{u}_i|\leq \max_{j\in \{1, \ldots, n\}} |\boldsymbol{v}_j| \sum_{i=1}^n |\boldsymbol{u}_i| =\|\boldsymbol{v}\|_\infty
    \end{equation*}
because $\|\boldsymbol{u}\|_1=1$ and applying the maximum to both sides we find that
$$ \|\boldsymbol{v}\|_{\infty}=\sup _{\|\boldsymbol{u}\|_1=1}\left|\boldsymbol{v}^* \boldsymbol{u}\right|=\max _{\|\boldsymbol{u}\|_1=1}\left|\boldsymbol{v}^* \boldsymbol{u}\right|$$

Answer (score 1):

It should be quite easy to verify that the function
$$
f(u)=|\langle v,u\rangle|
$$
attains its maximum for $u=e_j$ under the constrain $||u||=1$, where $j$ is the coordinate of $v$ with maximum absolute value.

Comment: What has this answer to do with that $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ norm?

Comment: $||v||_{\infty}=max_{j}|v_j|$, so the argument should prove the statement

Comment: Which scalar product are you using in your answer?

Comment: The scalar product that induces norm 2

Comment: But this problem is about the $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ norm, not the $\|\cdot\|_2$ norm.